# Downsampling (decimation) from 500Hz to 1Hz R

Tags: r, r-caret, sample

I have a data.frame df containing skin temperature over time of a bunch of people. The measuring frequency was 500Hz and I would like to downsample to 1Hz whilst RETAINING the first value for each "id". Problem is that each id's samples are of different lengths. *I cannot use the caret package because it won't install for me, which is not ideal.*

Any help would be much very appreciated.

```
df<-data.frame(Time=seq(65),
               SkinTemp=rnorm(65,37,0.5),
               id=rep(1:10,c(5,4,10,6,7,8,9,8,4,4)))
```

My first stab is this but the function says argument length 0:

```
#First values 
firstVal<-aggregate(data=df,SkinTemp~id,head,1)

sampledVals<-
    lapply(unique(df$id),function(x)df[sample(1:nrow(df$Time[df["id"]==x]), 5),])
```

Comment: How would your expected output look like?

Comment: Good question, I'd like a data.frame with the same column names as df and take a specific number of rows from Time & SkinTemp for each id. E.g. id==1 has currently 5 observation pairs; I'd like to average over each second. So that would be average every 500 samples for each id(Time,SkinTemp).

Comment: Your functions returns argument length 0 probably for one of two reasons. One, you are calling `nrow(df$Time[df["id"] == x])`, but the result of the subsetting is a vector, so you might want to use `length` instead.
Two, in your call to `sample`, you are setting `size = 5`, that's larger than some groups, without `replace = TRUE`, this can't be done.